# Converting to appropriate date format from a given long date

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a date in format like that -

```
date= "2 march 2018"
```

I want to convert it to the format "20180302". i am using following method for that :

```
var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

return [year, month, day].join('');
```

Everything works fine except that if my date has no date or month, it should return empty value in place of date and month. For example: If my date input is

```
date= "march 2018"
```

than, day = '' + d.getDate() should return empty. if date is "2018" than  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1) and  day = '' + d.getDate() should return null. I know it is a bad practise,but in my application I need to check if date and month is present of not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var date= "2 march 2018";
  var sp_date=date.split(" ");
  var d = new Date(date);
  if(sp_date.length==3){
  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  day = '' + d.getDate();
    year = d.getFullYear();
}else if(sp_date.length==2){
  if(isNaN(Number(sp_date[0]))===false){
    day = sp_date[0];
    month='';
    year=sp_date[1];
  }else{
  day ='';
   month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
     year = d.getFullYear();
  }
}else if(sp_date.length==1){
   day ='';
   month = '';
     year = d.getFullYear();
}


return [year, month, day].join('');
```

Comment: but there is an error in if(Number(sp_date[0])=== true). Its saying "===" cannot be applied to type number and boolean

Comment: I changed it to if(Number(sp_date[0])) , and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single line using moment.js, Check the jsfiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/46813/

```
var date = moment("2 march 2018").format('YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: for input "march 2918", the result is still coming as 20180301